# Determinar a chave de um dicionário que contém a maior quantidade de valores

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
animals = { 'a': ['aardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati']}

animals['d'] = ['donkey']
animals['d'].append('dog')
animals['d'].append('dingo')
```

Seja o dicionário `animals` definido acima. A função aplicada a ele deve devolver a chave "d":

```
biggest(animals)
```

resultado: 'd'

O meu código:

```
def biggest(aDict):
    '''
    aDict: A dictionary, where all the values are lists.

    returns: The key with the largest number of values associated with it
    '''


    maior = []
    key_maior = []
    for i in aDict.keys():
        #print(i)
        key_maior.append(i)
        maior.append(len(aDict[i]))
    #print(key_maior)
    #print(maior)



    maximo = max(maior)
    #print(maximo)
    #print(maior.index(maximo))
    return key_maior[maior.index(maximo)]


animals = { 'a': ['aardvark'], 'b': ['baboon'], 'c': ['coati']}

animals['d'] = ['donkey']
animals['d'].append('dog')
animals['d'].append('dingo')


print(biggest(animals))
```

O código funciona mas eu acho que está muito mal escrito. Existe uma outra maneira de resolver o problema?

Answer (score 4):

Analisando um pouco o seu código vejo duas coisas a salientar:

- `for i in aDict.keys():` - Aqui está a iterar sobre as chaves, mas depois acede aos valores em `len(aDict[i])`. Melhor seria então iterar sobre os items que já tem acesso às duas coisas: `for chave, valor in aDict.items():`
- Guardar a lista de todos os tamanhos para achar o máximo chamando `max` torna-se ineficiente. Mais eficiente seria guardar logo o maior à medida que compara.

Considerando esses dois pontos que disse, o seu programa ficaria assim:

```
def biggest(aDict):
    '''
    aDict: A dictionary, where all the values are lists.

    returns: The key with the largest number of values associated with it
    '''

    maior = 0
    chave_maior = None
    for chave, valor in aDict.items():
        if len(valor) > maior:
            maior = len(valor)
            chave_maior = chave

    return chave_maior
```

[Veja este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/fhtSH5)

Agora para ser verdadeiramente idiomatico em Python tem que fazer uso das ferramentas que já existem. A função nativa `max` permite passar uma função para indicar como é feita a comparação dos elementos para achar o máximo. Pode fazer uso disso indicando que a comparação é feita com base no tamanho das listas de cada entrada:

```
def biggest(aDict):
    '''
    aDict: A dictionary, where all the values are lists.

    returns: The key with the largest number of values associated with it
    '''

    return max(aDict, key=lambda x: len(aDict[x]))
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/femRo9)

Note que implementei a função de comparação com uma *lambda* para ser mais curto. Nesta disse que para cada elemento `x` a comparação era feita pelo `len(aDict[x])`, ou seja, pelo tamanho do valor referente a essa chave.